# Expose function variables, locally, within component

Tags: javascript, twitter-flight

I have a flightJS component (don't start) and need a way to expose the translated text from `bindTranslations` after my component has been initialized so that local functions can access the translated values. This is pseudo code of how I would like it to work, but my JS knowledge is failing me :(

```
function paymentForm() {
  this.bindTranslations = function() {
    var buttonText = I18n.t('js.process_payment_button');
    var paragraphText = I18n.t('js.process_payment_paragraph');

    return {
      button: buttonText,
      paragraph: paragraphText
    }
  };  

  this.handlePaymentState = function() {
    this.select('submitButtons').val(buttonText);
    this.select('paymentParagraph').val(paragraphText);
  }

  this.after('initialize', function() {
    this.bindTranslations();
  }
}

export default paymentForm;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move declarations of `buttonText` and `paragraphText` up one level to `parmentForm`. They will be captured in closure in `bindTranslations` and `handlePaymentState`:

```
function paymentForm() {
  var buttonText;
  var paragraphText;
  this.bindTranslations = function() {
    buttonText = I18n.t('js.process_payment_button');
    paragraphText = I18n.t('js.process_payment_paragraph');

    // ...
```

Comment: They may need to be referenced multiple times within a component from different methods - hence the global definition requirement.

Comment: They will be available from all methods (`this.blablah = function() {`) inside `paymentForm`.